# Calculating minimum number of comparisons to ensure 1 and only 1 value set

Tags: optimization

This is a math problem with software limitations.

I am forced to work with a very inflexible tool and must check 5 fields, each of which can be one of 4 values (or left unset), to ensure that 1 and only 1 field is set with any of the 4 values.  I cannot directly compare two fields, nor can I compare a field to null/0/unset.  The interface is a horrible web based page, that only allows extremely simple logic to be input, via drop down menus, line by line.

The only pseudo logic I can use is as follows:

```
if <field> <equals/not equals> <val> [<and/or>] 
if <field> <equals/not equals> <val> [<and/or>]
...

Where:
<field> is limited to field1, field2, ..., field5
<val> is limited to val1, val2, val3, val4
[<and/or>] is optional and would lead in to the following line
```

Each single line of "if" statement is one entry.  I know very little about the backend, but what I have gathered from testing is that "and" seems to be a higher precedence than "or".  There is also an arbitrary limit (that I have no idea what it is) on the number of lines, so the fewer lines the better.

This "ruleset" is basically one giant "if" statement that will be run through, and eventually return true or false.  The actions of true or false are determined outside of this ruleset, so the only thing I need to focus on here is the minimum number of steps to ensure that 1 and only 1 field has a value set, and a way to calculate how many entries are needed for that single ruleset given X fields with Y values.  My goal is to calculate all of this out, so I can mathematically prove that doing this is a waste of time and the backend needs to be fixed.  I have to make dozens of rulesets like this, all with different numbers of fields and values.

It seems to me that the only way to use this logic would be to check:

```
if field1 = val1 and 
if field2 = val1 or
if field1 = val1 and 
if field2 = val2 or
...
if field1 = val1 and
if field2 = val4 or
if field1 = val2 and
if field2 = val1 or
...
```

This is walking across all of the fields and values to to check if any two pairs of fields both have *some* value set.  When this whole ruleset returns true, it means that more than one field had a value set.  I believe the equation that models this is as follows:

```
((4*4*4)+(3*4*4)+(2*4*4)+(1*4*4))*2 = 320
```

This is walking each pair of fields without repeating since order does not matter, (1&2, 1&3, 1&4, 1&5, 2&3, 2&4, 2&5, 3&4, 3&5, 4&5), and comparing one value against the other 4, 4 times per pair of fields (one for each possible value).  The *2 at the end is because this math is assuming that comparing one field value to another is a single step, while in reality that requires two steps to do.

I do not believe there is any faster way to walk through all of the values, and I believe my math is correct.  If either of these or wrong, or can be optimized, please let me know.

As brought up in the comments, this could be scripted, yes.  However, there are a vast number of things wrong with this setup as a whole and I would rather objectively show that it needs to be fixed, rather than working around it.

Comment: Can you copy the field value and manipulate the copy?

Comment: If you had internal variables, you could get away with 25 comparisons.

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger No, unfortunately the tool I am working with is not able to do this.  The only operations I can perform are as I said in the question.  The configuration of it is through a graphical interface.  My goal is to find the least number of steps to accomplish what needs to be done, and the function to calculate the number of steps needed.

Comment: Too bad.  If you can't set variables, you can't do things like 'if field1 has value1 then set var1 to var1+1', which would cut down on the number of tests needed.

Comment: Are you allowed to do anything?  As written, there is an `if` test, but nothing specifying what you are allowed to do after the test passes.  Do you need to do this with a single big `if` test, or can you nest them?

Comment: @CortAmmon Its basically one big ass if statement, the pseudo-code I posted is literally all I can do.  There is no nesting, no looping, nothing.  Its all done through a graphical input with dropdown lists.  All I can do is add another line beginning with an "if" and either ending with <val> or "and" or "or" and another line below it.  All of the lines are interpreted in order from top to bottom.  What happens when this giant statement is evaluated is defined outside of the scope of this.

Comment: Wow, that's... a challenge.  Does it do operator precidence (ands bind more tightly than ors) or shortcutting (once it can prove the answer is true or false, it stops trying)?  And you mention its graphical... is there any way of scripting the work? (if it's a webpage based gui, we can hand-code replies in a scripting language to do the work for you)

Comment: I am _assuming_ it has operator precedence, with and being higher than or; this is based on a couple of tests I have run.  But I am not privy to the internals of this system and do not truly know, and I have not received a response from the tool creators (this is a nightmare, I know).  I am trying to find the number of steps its going to take so I can go to my superiors and say "its going to day X amount of hours to do this one ruleset" to hopefully light a fire under the higher ups to get this fixed.

Comment: It is web based, and I could probably script the input of it.  But I can address that when the time comes, and would rather see this system get fixed, than to continually work around it.

Comment: Okay, this one will be embarrassing, but it strikes me if you have 5 fields, each of which takes on one of 4 values... doesn't that imply 100% of forms have a field appear twice by the pigeonhole principle?  What am I missing?

Comment: My apologies, a field CAN be not set.  However, there is no way with the testing logic above to check whether or not a value is set, you can only compare it to a known value.  The goal is to check whether one and only one field has a value set.  Based on this back and forth, I am going to edit the original question to try and clarify it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your answer is as cheap as it can be done.  However, in the process of trying to work out the logic, I found I needed to come up with a more standard definition of the problem and the language you face, so I wanted to include it here.  It may be helpful, so I included it here before the answer.

Consider if I modeled the data you are receiving as a grid:

```
        blank  val1  val2  val3  val4
       +-----------------------------+
field1 | X                           |
field2 |              X              |
field3 | X                           |
field4 | X                           |
field5 |                          X  | <--// error - 2 fields set
       +-----------------------------+
```

What do we know about this setup:

- No row can contain more than one X, because a field can only have one value
- Your `field = value` and `field != value` tests are identical to querying the state of one square on the board.
- The goal is to verify that all fields are blank, except  for one of them.

Now the grammar you have access to is important.  We're not just looking for positions, we're looking for a minimal set of rules expressed in this grammar to test those positions.  I will assume, from your comments, that the grammar is a [Sum of Products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_normal_form) (SoP) form where "and" takes precedence over "or," and there are no parenthesis to create nested expressions.

For brevity, I'm going to invent a shorter syntax, using `x13` to means "is there an x for field 1, val3."  This just makes it shorter to write, and is perfectly translatable into `if field1 = val3`.  Let's also use `!x13` to means `if field1 != val3`, which is the typical meaning of `!` in C based programming languages. I will use SoP notation so `x12*x23 + !x34` means:

```
if field1 = val2 <and>
if field2 = val3 <or>
if field3 != val4
```

This also has a huge advantage of now using typical mathematical operator precedence, so I can avoid wasting lots of space with parenthesis (though I may use them where convenient).  However, as a side effect of the limits in your language, blanks have to be tested by negation, so I can never test `x30`, I must instead test `!x31*!x32*!x33*!x34`.  This will be important later

So now your example of

```
if field1 = val1 and 
if field2 = val1 or
if field1 = val1 and 
if field2 = val2 or
...
if field1 = val1 and
if field2 = val4 or
if field1 = val2 and
if field2 = val1 or
...
```

can be written as `[(f11*f21) + (f11*f22) + ... + (f11*f24)] + [(f12*f21) + (f11*f22) + ... + (f11*f24)]`, with parenthesis and brackets provided for clarity.  Now we know something important with this: any other valid notation must be logically equivalent to this one.  We also know that the equation must be in SoP form.  There's a lot of solutions available if we could do a bigger hierarchy than this.

I recommend this notation, because doing SoP optimization is standard hat for microelectronics engineers.  We've been doing it a long time, so we know all of the tricks.

**Now, with that notation aside, to solve the problem**

Consider the following information:

- Any one query (field = value) cannot contain enough information to detect a failure, because legally any field *can* have any value.

  - It takes a minimum of two terms to detect a failure.  They will always be d together because it is in SoP form.
  - No new information is gathered by combining 3 terms with .  For any 3 terms linked with , any non-failing input would have not-failed with fewer terms.  Any failing input would have failed with 2 terms because the third term is a 'dont-care.'
- <and> takes precedence, meaning you must build a list of failure-detection expressions, and then <or> them together to detect the failures.
- These rules put together points out that an answer which only ever combines 2 queries (like your answer) will always be more efficient than an answer involving 3 queries.

  - Thus we only have to consider if there is a combination of rules in the form (x1*y1)+(x2*y2)+(x3*y3)+... which can be more efficient than your set.

The only possible way to detect a failure with this form is to have both x1 and y1 be terms that query a field that was not-blank.  The only possible way to catch that is to test every possible pair.  It is trivial to show that, if you skip a pair, you can miss an invalid input.

The only thing we can mix to possibly beat more value out of SoP is negation.  So far we've only talked about testing for equality.  Unfortunately, due to the language you have, it doesn't help.  If I negate any test, such as `!x32`, that is identical to `x30 + x31 + x33 + x34`.  Unfortunately, there is no where in your logic where it is helpful to lump a blank like `x30` in with values like `x31` using .  Thus the only negation that would be useful to you is `!x30`, but as you mentioned, you can't test a blank, so the only useful negation is not possible.

All of this suggests that there are other ways to do it, but they will all require the same amount of steps that your solution requires, or worse.

Comment: Awesome.  Its been a little while since I've done any kind of math like this, but the way you put it together makes a good bit of sense.